# default source is not working for android in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to show image placeholder before the actual image loaded from the server.

For iOS, defaultSource prop is working fine but for android the image is not getting displayed.

```
<Image style={dashBoardStyles.buildingImage} source={{ uri: 'some server image' }} defaultSource={ require('../images/loadingindicatorImage.png')}>
```

Can anyone help regarding this issue.

Comment: In react native documentation 'Note: On Android, the default source prop is ignored on debug builds.' Check with your release build

Comment: Yes, I even tried in release build too. But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please read https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#defaultsource carefully, and you'll find below note.

Note: On Android, the default source prop is ignored on debug builds.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32015537)